# What's the best way to use set of upgrade scripts in fpm?

Tags: linux, rpm, packaging

I'm using fpm package builder and try to use flags:

`--after-upgrade=upgrade.sh` or `--before-upgrade=upgrade.sh`.

But I didn't found how to use directories or sets of scripts with these params.

I have a directory with several update scripts (in general case in different languages):

```
.../updates/
  - update1.sql
  - update1.sh
  - update2.rb
  - update2.sh
  - ...
```

How can I execute multiple scripts in this case?

For example, I want to execute `update1.sql` and `update1.sh` during first upgrade, `update2.rb` and `update2.sh` during second upgrade, and all others at third upgrade.

Is there a better idea than to merge all scripts into one `upgrade.sh` before upgrading?